# Can HttpServlet.setHeader() throw an exception if some content is sent?

Tags: servlets, http-headers

I already know that if you try to set a http header once part of the content is sent, an error should be raised or the header should be ignored. This is part of the common sense.

My question is if java [HttpServlet.setHeader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or addHeader throws an exception in that cases or are silently ignored. AFAIK the documentation doesn't show much help.

I've seen errors in a was server reflecting an error like that, but appears to be an error raised than a filter rather than an error of the application itself.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is in [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf):

> ## 5.2 Headers
>
> ...
>
> To be successfully transmitted back to the client, headers must be set before the
>   response is committed. **Headers set *after* the response is committed will be ignored
>   by the servlet container.**
>
> ...

So, no exception.